# concatenating multiple column with separator

Tags: sql-server

I want to concat a multiple column of table with separator "|" but if null data in some column separator should not come

E.g
Table

```
+----+------+---------+-----+
|Code| M1   |   M2    |M3   | 
+----+------+---------+-----+
|1000| ABC  | MNO     | XYZ |
|1002| 123  | xyz     |     |
|1009| ABC1 |         |     |
|1003|      |         |     |
+----+------+-- ------+- ---+
```

Desire Output

```
+----+---------------+
|Code|   MOD         |
+----+---------------+
|1000|  ABC|MNO|XYZ  | 
|1002|  123|xyz      | 
|1009|  ABC1         |
|1003|               |
+----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems an interesting question. To facilitate the copy & paste test, I hereby provide my version based on the solution from @Daniel Hutmacher.

You can play by replacing / adding different values in the population script.

```
create table #t (code int, m1 varchar(10), m2 varchar(10), m3 varchar(10));
go
insert into #t (code, m1, m2, m3)
values (1000, 'ABC', 'MNO', 'XYZ')
, (1002, '123', NULL, '')
, (1009, 'ABC1', '', NULL)
, (1003, NULL, '', NULL)
, (1004, NULL, 'DEF', NULL)
, (1005, 'Hello','  ', 'World')

GO


SELECT [Code],
       SUBSTRING(
           ISNULL('|'+nullif(ltrim(m1),''), '')+
           ISNULL('|'+nullif(ltrim(m2),''), '')+
           ISNULL('|'+nullif(ltrim(m3),''), ''), 2, 1000) AS [MOD]
FROM #t
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ISNULL function,

```
SELECT [Code],
       SUBSTRING(
           ISNULL('|'+m1, '')+
           ISNULL('|'+m2, '')+
           ISNULL('|'+m3, '')+
           ISNULL('|'+m4, ''), 2, 1000) AS [MOD]
```

So, if `m1` is NULL, `ISNULL('|'+m1, '')` will return `''`, otherwise it will return `'|'+m1`. Add all the columns together like that, then use `SUBSTRING()` to remove the first leading `|`.

Note: for this solution to work, I'm assuming that you have `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON` (this is the default setting, but just in case).

Comment: but when some values are null it showing "|||"

Comment: Have you set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL in your connection flags? Are the empty values NULL or just blank?

Comment: Sounds like your columns are empty strings rather than NULL values, @AmolNaik .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments that [Daniel Hutmacher's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210387/116365) is not working, it appears that your data contains either empty strings or spaces.

Here's a select statement that ought to fix this.

```
Select [Code], 
  SubString(
     case when len(isnull(m1,'')) = 0 then '' else '|' + m1 end + 
     case when len(isnull(m2,'')) = 0 then '' else '|' + m2 end + 
     case when len(isnull(m3,'')) = 0 then '' else '|' + m3 end + 
     case when len(isnull(m4,'')) = 0 then '' else '|' + m4 end 
   , 2, 1000) as [MOD]
```

This is says if the value for m1 is null or has no length (an empty string), then return an empty string.

If that doesn't work, you can also change the len statement to  `len(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(m1,''))))` to remove any leading or trailing spaces before checking the value's length.